# Fetching data from tags using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

So i try to fetch the data from pre tag, i set doc connect to url select pre tag and the result gone wrong, the data i need to fetch press
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkNWV.png)

```
String url="http://api.airvisual.com/v2/countries?key=9c2dd8c2-1053-43fa-9357-6d3aa876aabc";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  for(Element a: doc.select("pre"))
  {
  System.out.println(a.text());
  }
```

Comment: The <pre> is prepared by the browser. It is not there in the http response. What the server give you is a pure json.

Comment: so i have to use httpurlconnection instead of jsoup or there is another to fetch the data by using jsoup?

Comment: Jsoup is a html parser. Since the API data is json not html, it doesn't fit your need. You are doing 2 thing in your code actually. Download the data from the API and print it. If that is what you need, then yes, HttpURLConnection is good enough. If you further need to parse the data or manipulate them, maybe you need a json library.

Comment: i see,thanks for your tip sir

Comment: hold on - JSoup is an html parser yes, but its also a capable web client as well. This should be doable... bear with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;

class AirVisualJsonData {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://api.airvisual.com/v2/countries?key=9c2dd8c2-1053-43fa-9357-6d3aa876aabc";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();
        for (Element node : document.select("body")) {
            System.out.println(node.text());
        }
    }
}
```

But you'll want to be able to parse the json you get back using a Json parser. There are many to choose from. Gson, Jackson, Jayway, etc. You'll have to pick what's right for you.

Output:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "country": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Algeria"
    },
    {
      "country": "Andorra"
    },
    {
      "country": "Angola"
    },
    {
      "country": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "country": "Armenia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Austria"
    },
    {
      "country": "Bahamas"
    },
    {
      "country": "Bahrain"
    },
    {
      "country": "Bangladesh"
    },
    {
      "country": "Belgium"
    },
    {
      "country": "Bosnia Herzegovina"
    },
    {
      "country": "Brazil"
    },
    {
      "country": "Brunei"
    },
    {
      "country": "Bulgaria"
    },
    {
      "country": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "country": "Chile"
    },
    {
      "country": "China"
    },
    {
      "country": "Colombia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Croatia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Cyprus"
    },
    {
      "country": "Czech Republic"
    },
    {
      "country": "Denmark"
    },
    {
      "country": "Ecuador"
    },
    {
      "country": "Ethiopia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Finland"
    },
    {
      "country": "France"
    },
    {
      "country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "country": "Ghana"
    },
    {
      "country": "Guatemala"
    },
    {
      "country": "Hong Kong SAR"
    },
    {
      "country": "Hungary"
    },
    {
      "country": "India"
    },
    {
      "country": "Indonesia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Iran"
    },
    {
      "country": "Iraq"
    },
    {
      "country": "Ireland"
    },
    {
      "country": "Israel"
    },
    {
      "country": "Italy"
    },
    {
      "country": "Ivory Coast"
    },
    {
      "country": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Jordan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Kazakhstan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Kosovo"
    },
    {
      "country": "Kuwait"
    },
    {
      "country": "Kyrgyzstan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Latvia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Lithuania"
    },
    {
      "country": "Luxembourg"
    },
    {
      "country": "Macao SAR"
    },
    {
      "country": "Malaysia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Malta"
    },
    {
      "country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "country": "Mongolia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Myanmar"
    },
    {
      "country": "Nepal"
    },
    {
      "country": "Netherlands"
    },
    {
      "country": "New Caledonia"
    },
    {
      "country": "New Zealand"
    },
    {
      "country": "Nigeria"
    },
    {
      "country": "North Macedonia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Norway"
    },
    {
      "country": "Oman"
    },
    {
      "country": "Pakistan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Peru"
    },
    {
      "country": "Philippines"
    },
    {
      "country": "Poland"
    },
    {
      "country": "Portugal"
    },
    {
      "country": "Puerto Rico"
    },
    {
      "country": "Romania"
    },
    {
      "country": "Russia"
    },
    {
      "country": "San Marino"
    },
    {
      "country": "Serbia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Singapore"
    },
    {
      "country": "Slovakia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Slovenia"
    },
    {
      "country": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "country": "South Korea"
    },
    {
      "country": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "country": "Sri Lanka"
    },
    {
      "country": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "country": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "country": "Syria"
    },
    {
      "country": "Taiwan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Thailand"
    },
    {
      "country": "Turkey"
    },
    {
      "country": "U.S. Virgin Islands"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA"
    },
    {
      "country": "Uganda"
    },
    {
      "country": "Ukraine"
    },
    {
      "country": "United Arab Emirates"
    },
    {
      "country": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "country": "Uzbekistan"
    },
    {
      "country": "Vietnam"
    },
    {
      "country": "Yemen"
    }
  ]
}
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: i figured it out from your code and i switched it to plain text thanks for the tip